# Aggregation of degree if column B 'nodeName' (word) matches in column A 'comment_text' (sentence)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregate-functions

I have a dataframe having 3 columns.

Column A : sentences

Column B : NodeName

Column C : Degrees of each node.

[Dataframe columns][1]

I want to match every Nodename present in column B with every sentence in column A and if that NodeName is present in the sentence in column A then sum of their respective degrees for every row needs to be stored in a new column in the dataframe like DegreeSum.

```
nodenames = ['canada','government','hope','conservative','harper']
pat = '|'.join(sorted(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in nodenames))
finaldfnew['NodeMatch']=finaldfnew["comment_text"].str.findall(pat).apply(", ".join)
finaldfnew
```

In above code I store some node names in the list and match them with my sentences column and store the matching nodes in new column.

[For example node name like "hope, Conservative" matched with the first row of sentence column. Then i store these matching nodes in new "Node Match" column.][2]

Now I want to add the degrees of matching nodes and sum the average degree into new column like "Degree Sum".

```
comment_text    NodeName    Degree  Degree Sum
I am Nauman.           I       2        2+3=5
Cricket is game.   Nauman      3        4
I love Pakistan.   Cricket     4        2
```

Comment: Provide a sample of your dataframe as code and not screenshots. Use `df.head().to_dict()`. Also include your expected output

Comment: I have updated the post and add the desired output.